# xlwings cannot change font below row 6

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

So here's the code I wrote to change the font in my xlsx file output:

```
wb = xw.Book('aapl.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets('Sheet1')
last_cell = sht.range("A1").end(Direction.xlDown).end(Direction.xlToRight)
print('Last cell at: (' + str(last_cell.column) + ', ' + str(last_cell.row) + ')' + '\n')

for i in range(1, last_cell.column):
    for j in range(1, last_cell.row):
        sht.cells(i, j).api.Font.Name = 'JetBrains Mono'

for ws in wb.sheets:
    ws.autofit(axis='columns')

wb.save()
```

and the problem here is: I want to set the font type to `JetBrains Mono` in my file, but I don't know why it can only change to sixth row. I have tried to print out the location of `last_cell` to see if I made any mistakes, and also swapped out `last_row.column` in the second for loop to see if `range(1, 107)` (107 is the row count in my file) works. But, still ended up with this unfortunately. [how the file I ended up getting looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH8dM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can simplify in your code:

- You can apply a font to a range of cells, you don't need to loop through each cell
- meanwhile, xlwings has support for `font.name` without having to use the `api` workaround
- `expand` or `current_region` should make your life easier

This code should be all you need:

```
wb = xw.Book('aapl.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

sht['A1'].expand().font.name = 'JetBrains Mono'
```

Comment: Thank you this method worked perfectly. But is there any flaws in my code above that's stopping me from getting the correct output? I didn't see the mistakes in looping through the cells each by each. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Seanmamasde In your code you swapped row and column indizes. Change `sht.cells(i, j)` in `sht.cells(j, i)`.

Comment: It turned out the definition of "row" and "column" are reversed here in China. Now I understood, thanks(Never noticed this before). And I also forgot to put `+1` after `last_cell.column` and `last_cell.row` so it'll make it to the last cell in the spreadsheet.